# Beautify scientific notation in Excel 2011

Tags: excel, vba

Excel displays scientific notation like this "1.00E+03" by default. Is there a way to make it more appealing to the eyes? I am thinking of something like this:

[image]

This should be possible with unicode characters, but I don't have previous experience with VBA. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: If you format the cells as number it will not show the scientific notation.  But i'm not sure if you can change it.

Comment: This looks promising..  http://excel.tips.net/T009234_Custom_Formats_for_Scientific_Notation.html  Let us know if it works.

Comment: Just tried it before posting the question. The result was awful.

Comment: You can specify a custom format, but I'm not sure that will be enough for 2 reasons : You need to determine the power of ten that will left you with a single digit before decimal and you'd have to put that into exponant (which *can't be done in a format* (I guess, although I'm pretty about this one)). *That maybe possible via VBA*, but it'll most probably need to **store your value as text/string** so I guess it'll lost all purpose of a simple column. Maybe an add-in can solve this but I'm not sure...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have data like:

[image]

Select the cells and run this macro:

```
Option Explicit

Sub dural()
   Dim t As String, np As String, midl As String
   Dim signp As String, i As Long, ary, expp As String
   Dim msg As String, neg As Boolean, r As Range
   midl = " x 10"
   ary = Split("8304,185,178,179,8308,8309,8310,8311,8312,8313", ",")
   For Each r In Selection
      msg = ""
      t = r.Text
      If Left(t, 1) = "-" Then
         neg = True
         t = Mid(t, 2)
      Else
         neg = False
      End If

      np = Mid(t, 1, 4)
      signp = Mid(t, 6, 1)
      If signp = "+" Then
         signp = ChrW(8314)
      Else
         signp = ChrW(8315)
      End If

      expp = Mid(t, 7)
      If Left(expp, 1) = "0" Then expp = Mid(expp, 2)
      For i = 1 To Len(expp)
         msg = msg & ChrW(ary(CLng(Mid(expp, i, 1))))
      Next i

      msg = np & midl & signp & msg
      If neg Then msg = "-" & msg
      msg = Chr(34) & msg & Chr(34)
      r.NumberFormat = msg & ";" & msg & ";" & msg & ";"
   Next r
End Sub
```

To produce:

[image]

***NOTE:***

1. only the formats have changed, not the underlying values
2. assumes the cells have constants, not formulas
3. font supports unicode

Answer (score 0):

This procedure will work (it turns the numbers for the exponent into superscript, so should work for any font):

```
Option Explicit

Sub SciIt(ModCell As String)

Dim cl As Range
Dim Form As String

Set cl = Range(ModCell)
If IsNumeric(cl.Value) Then
    Form = Format(cl.Value, "0.00E+0")
    cl.Value = Left(Form, InStr(Form, "E") - 1) & " x 10" & Mid(Form, InStr(Form, "E") + 1)
    cl.Characters(Start:=InStr(cl.Value, "x") + 4).Font.Superscript = True
End If

End Sub
```

Note that this will destroy the value that was in there previously, so if you need to use the number for a formula, keep a copy somewhere else. It will also lose the link to a previous cell, so if the original value changes, then you will have to re-enter the formula, and run this again.

Comment: How do you actually use this?

Comment: from code (or immediate window) use something like `SciIt "C5"` and it will convert the number in C5 to the format in your question

Comment: Hm. The exponent is still not rendered as superscript. At least not on Mac OSX.

Comment: Also, is it possible to use unicode U+00D7 instead of 'x'? That would look much better.

Comment: you can use any character you want - just change it in both places that you see the current `x`.  Unfortunately, I don't know about Office for Mac. recording a macro should give you a hint on what is uses for the font adjustment

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a Scala script that does the job perfectly well:

```
import java.awt.Toolkit
import java.awt.datatransfer.{StringSelection, DataFlavor}

/**
 * Created by IDEA on 13/10/15.
 */
object Scientific {
  val superscriptMap = {
    var tmp = collection.mutable.Map(
      '0' -> '\u2070',
      '1' -> '\u00b9',
      '2' -> '\u00b2',
      '3' -> '\u00b3'
    )
    val x = ('4' to '9').zip('\u2074' to '\u2079').toList
    for ((k, v) <- x) {
      tmp.update(k, v)
    }
    tmp.toMap
  }
  type ExponentTuple = (Int, String)

  def dealWithSign(s: String): ExponentTuple = {
    if (s.head == '+') {
      (1, s.tail.dropWhile(_ == '0'))
    } else if (s.head == '-') {
      (-1, s.tail.dropWhile(_ == '0'))
    } else {
      (1, s)
    }
  }

  def snBeautify(s: String): String = {
    val s1 = s.split("[Ee]").take(2)
    require(s1.length == 2)
    val coefficient = s1(0)
    val (sign, exponent) = dealWithSign(s1(1))
    val part1 = coefficient + '\u00d7' + "10"
    val part2 = exponent.map(superscriptMap(_))
    // if the number is negative, provide a superscript minus
    if (sign < 0) part1 + '\u207b' + part2
    else part1 + part2
  }

  def snBeautify1(s: String): String = {
    s.split("\\s").map(snBeautify(_)).mkString("\n")
  }

  def snBeautify(printOut: Boolean = true): Unit = {
    val toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit
    val clipboard = toolkit.getSystemClipboard
    val s1 = clipboard.getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor).asInstanceOf[String]
    val s2 = snBeautify1(s1)
    val s2Select = new StringSelection(s2)
    if (printOut) println(s2)
    clipboard.setContents(s2Select, s2Select)
  }
}

object Test1 {
  //  val s = List("4.2E+5", "4.2e5", "4.2e-5", "4.2E-5", "-4.2e-5")
  //  s.map(snBeautify(_))
  //  snBeautify1(s.mkString("\n"))
  //  val s1 = "1.74E-11\n2.72E-12\n2.20E-11\n2.20E-11\n2.20E-11\n2.20E-11\n2.20E-11\n2.20E-11\n2.20E-11\n2.20E-11\n2.20E-11\n6.42E-12\n7.13E-11\n4.02E-11\n7.84E-12\n5.87E-12\n1.55E-11\n1.07E-10\n1.04E-10\n3.81E-11\n4.46E-11\n4.46E-11\n4.46E-11\n4.46E-11\n1.23E-10\n2.45E-11\n8.24E-12"
  //  snBeautify1(s1)
  // Copy the cells you want to reformat first
  Scientific.snBeautify()
}
```

Not a native Excel solution, but at least Scala is much nicer than VBA.

You can copy the cells you want to reformat and then run the `snBeautify` function, the reformatted numbers now sits in the clipboard ready for you to paste into Excel or Word.

One advantage of this solution is that it's equally applicable to LibreOffice or OpenOffice.

You can also easily modify this into a shell script and bind it to a certain keyboard shortcut.